# sql query to retrieve only those columns names starting with some alphabet

Tags: sql-server

I want to retrieve only those columns which start with some alphabet such as 'st1' .How to do so in sql query??

I have a table name Radiof whcih has around 1080 columns .I want to retrieve only those column names(**I'm taking about column name not column value**)whcih start with "st1_".
Can we do this through sql query in sql server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM Database.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%st1%'
```

Or

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INDUS2_RF.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'main_rf_analog' And COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%st1%'
```

check this from more info. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933204%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Comment: Can I write Column_name at palce of Table_Name ,as I want column names??

Comment: **select * from INDUS2_RF.dbo.main_rf_analog where logtime between '2014-10-10 07:17:00' and '2014-10-10 08:47:00'**. This is my query now I want only those columns whose strating letter is st1_ .How to achieve this?? What to write at place of COLUMNS in your query??

Comment: I wrote **SELECT *
FROM INDUS2_RF.main_rf_analog.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%st1%'** but its showing error that **Invalid object name and invalid column name**

Comment: INDUS2_RF is you database name and main_rf_analog is your table name right?

Answer (score 1):

```
use database name

select * from tablename where columnname like 'st1%'
```